# Is this a valid way to solve $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log({x^2-x+1)}}{\log{(x^{10}+x^5+1)}}$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log({x^2-x+1)}}{\log{(x^{10}+x^5+1)}}=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log({x^2(1-1/x+1/x^2)}}{\log{(x^{10}(1+1/x^5+1/x^{10})}}=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\log({x^2})\log{(1-1/x+1/x^2)}}{\log{(x^{10})\log{(1+1/x^5+1/x^{10}})}}=\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2\log x}{10\log x}=1/5$$

Is it correct?

Comment: $\log(ab)=\log(a)+\log(b)$ not $\log(a)\cdot\log(b)$

Comment: @saulspatz thanks, should i close the question it is so simple after seeing the mistake

Comment: If it were me, I'd delete the question

Comment: But please don't delete the question, it is useful for anyone else who wonders the same thing.